# In BackgroundWorker: RunWorkerCompleted's e.Error == null even in case of error

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker, desktop-application

When I put try catch block around my time taking task. In RunWorkerCompleted() method e.error use to be null. When I remove try catch block then in RunWorkerCompleted() method e.error is not equal to null.

Why is this strange behaviour?

Code:

```
  public partial class LoginForm : Form
{
    private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    private static ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    enum status
    {
        Blank,
        Success,
        Error
    };

    public LoginForm()
    {
        InterimProceedings();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void InterimProceedings()
    {
        bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);

        if (!bw.IsBusy)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("BackgroundWorker is busy");
        }
    }

    private static void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
      //  Time taking task
          mre.Set();
    }

    private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(e.Error == null))
        {
            this.lbl_status.Text = "Cannot proceed, Error occured";
            appStatus = status.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            this.lbl_status.Text = "Good to go...";
            appStatus = status.Success;
        }
    }

    private void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mre.WaitOne();

        if(appStatus == status.Success)
        {
            // Proceed with intended work
        }

        else
        {
            // Pop-up error occurred
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Are you re-throwing the caught error? If not, what else did you expect? :)

Comment: In the form constructor, swap the call order of `InitializeComponent` and `InterimProceedings`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.Error has the exception that is thrown from DoWork. If you use a try/catch inside DoWork, there is no exception.

Comment: But if I do not catch exception, it freezes my UI and never calls mre.Set()

Comment: You may use try/finally.

Comment: No avail. Still doen't call mre.Set()

Comment: mre.Set in finally block?!

Comment: @Sadiq That will work. But no improvement whatsoever. You really need to do it asynchronously. I deleted my answer; this is the XY question. I repeat my comment here (That's the first problem to solve. Why are you using ManualResetEvent in first place? UI will freeze there when time taken to complete the work. If you can use TPL, start a Task and await it. Don't use BackgroundWorker at all )

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Please elaborate 'But no improvement whatsoever'.

Comment: @Sadiq I already did in my previous comment. UI will still freeze till the work is done. That will not give the user a good user experience. If you know what I mean.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I know that, but if your task is dependent on the result of task completion inside background worker, then i will have to wait. Besides background worker will be performing its task while user will be providing username and password.

Comment: @Sadiq You don't have to wait but `await` (wait asynchronously). Which means not blocking the UI. Learn about [asynchronous programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: I have actually shown an async implementation of this code in [your other question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/88657/71242).